# handling different charsets in xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml, character-encoding

i am generating an XML from mysql database using PHP for getting the name list. now some tags are not coming properly e.g. `(( دار الخير ))  هي مؤسسة خيرية في الاحساء .. تستق�` is coming in xml data which is creating problem for xml-parsher, then i change the output to utf8 encoding its comming like `ðŸŒ´ðŸŒ´(( Ø¯Ø§Ø± Ø§Ù„Ø®ÙŠØ± )) ðŸŒ´ðŸŒ´ Ù‡ÙŠ Ù…Ø¤Ø³Ø³Ø© Ø®ÙŠØ±ÙŠØ© ÙÙŠ Ø§Ù„Ø§Ø­Ø³Ø§Ø¡ .. ØªØ³ØªÙ‚Ø`.

i tried with

```
header ("content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

as well as

```
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

But no one is providing me Accurate result set. i tried to change the encoding but its not working. Is there any way i can get correct text?

Comment: what is the tables collation (`show create table`)? what is the encoding of original text (if this is entered from webform then it should be the websites encoding)?

Comment: its `latin1_swedish_ci`.

Answer (score 0):

*answer changed based on comments*

Seems like you have **some** of tha data in UTF8 already and this utf8 data is stored in mysql latin1 field as binary.

**Proof:**

```
select convert(binary convert ('دار الخير' using utf8) using latin1) 
,(convert (binary convert('Ø¯Ø§Ø± Ø§Ù„Ø®ÙŠØ±' using latin1)using utf8))
```

if you would have data in utf8 only then:

```
mysql_query('SET names latin1'); // this is probably arlready the default
```

you just need to set xml header to utf8:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

also, im not sure if php header is necessary:

```
header ("content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

**In your case** i am not sure if you have utf8 charset mixed with other charsets but my xml editor handles that text ok (i.e not giving an error) it treated as utf8.

if you have mixed charsets then its a pain in the ass.

cheers.

Comment: its not working i tried with `header ("content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
` and `mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
              mysql_query('SET names=utf8');
              mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
              mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
              mysql_query('SET collation_connection=utf8_general_ci');
` i am getting same result.